# Rewrite subdomain to subpath of another subdomain

Tags: next.js, cloudflare

If i have two NextJS project, a product.company.me site, and the docs hosted on docs.another.me, and I want in product.company.me/docs to render the docs.another.me site, how do I do it with cloudflare workers

Comment: Seems like you could do that with a simple page rule: https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/page-rules or, if you don't want the URL to change in the web browser, an origin rule https://developers.cloudflare.com/rules/origin-rules/ Why use a worker?